# When is vertex painting the right choice to color a model?

Tags: texturing, uv, vertex-colors

I am asking this question because I cannot think of any advantage to vertex painting over automatic uv unwrapping followed by texture painting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vertex color is faster to setup, and not needing any texture image or UV-unwrapping can be perceived as an advantage in itself. I've helped a colleague setting up his characters for an animation training DVD ([cover](http://toko.blenderindonesia.org/cover_dvd.png)). He uses mainly vertex color, and not resorting to complex lighting or texture tricks to convey subtly varied colors in each character.

Another project I've been involved in consumes 1.5GB of RAM when rendering, mostly for textures. This one's memory requirement would be orders of magnitude lower.

If your character design needs the detail, then using image/procedural texture would be justified. Otherwise, vertex color can be a viable alternative, especially on computers with less RAM to use.

Comment: since you could paint vertices only,that gives limit resolution of final look unless model isn't high poly

Comment: True, that's a major drawback that limits its applicability.

Comment: It's also possible to bake a vertex color layer using `bake full texture` in Blender Internal with a node setup, the process is a little convoluted but it works great for creating a base colour for texturing.

Comment: You often use both vertex-colors AND uv unwrap, especially with tiling textures, vertex-colors can help add some character and reduce obvious repeating-pattern artifacts.